# linux security attr set on windows

Tags: windows, security, attributes, kernel

Linux have Extended security attributes like *security*.attr_name.

Somebody told me, how i can, if can. Set this attribute for file on Windows.

example:
On windows we have file, 1.txt. 
Setting attr to file and copy on flash,
mount this flash on linux and read security attribute 1.txt wich we set on Windows.

add: May be something now linux module for cast EA/ADS from windows to linux attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Extended attributes aren't an OS feature but rather a filesystem feature. If you have a filesystem that supports extended attributes mounted on Windows you could modify them to be anything you like using the right tools.

Usually on windows you work with NTFS and FAT filesystems. Both lack extended attributes on Linux ASFAIK.

Comment: NTFS Extended Attributes are the closest thing to what the OP is looking for, security information could also possibly be stored in NTFS Alternate Data Streams